# Deallocating memory using double pointers

Tags: c++

Just a question about deallocation through a double pointer.

Would the following basic example be correct?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int **d = { new int*[3] };

    int * p = { new int[100] } ;
    p[0] = 300;

    int *x = new int(1);

    d[0] = p;
    d[1] = x;

    // pointer in d[0] is a pointer to an array
    // so use this:
    delete[] d[0]; 

    // pointer in d[1] is not a pointer to an array
    // so use this:
    delete d[1];  

    std::cout << p[0] << " " << x << '\n';

}
```

Comment: you access `p[0]` after `p` has been deleted, that is undefined behavior. Why would you write such code?

Comment: hi, yes the last line was a mistake, but rather just a way of trying to see what happened by the deletes

Comment: what is the qeustion exactly, if you already know it is wrong?

Comment: was the delete opertions done right?

Comment: "right" is relative. You shouldnt be using `new` and `delete` and raw owning pointers at all. There is no good reason to write such code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You (try to) access `p[0]` *after* your `delete[] d[0];` call, and `d[0]` has the `p` address as its value, so that `delete[]` call frees the `p` memory. This means your `cout` statement is *undefined behaviour* (when I run it, I get a 'random' value for `p[0]`).

Move the `cout` line to *before* the `delete[] d[0]` call, and you'll see the value of `300`.

Also, you never free the `d` array! Add this line to near the end of your main: `delete[] d;`.

Comment: its some corner I will perhaps never understand completly, so I am not sure, but `x` is just the pointer, not the pointee. Different for `p[0]`, which is UB for sure

Comment: @idclev463035818 Sorry, my mistake! (Typing too quickly... see edit.)

Comment: many thanks for feedback, was just a little confused about delete[] and delete ..thanks

Comment: @AfzelAdam Yes, your understanding of when to use `delete` and when to use `delete[]` is correct. If you change `delete d[1]` to `delete[] d[1]` and run the `clang-cl` analyser, you get: **note: Memory allocated by 'new' should be deallocated by 'delete', not 'delete[]'**.